# what will be the format of message to share on whatsapp , so user can select particular text

Tags: android, whatsapp, share-intent

As I am sharing image and text on whatsapp but not able to select particular text.. is there any workaround so i can copy on particular text on whatsapp ..As whatsapp doesnt give this option to copy part of a conversation but may be is there any way i can modify the message so user can easily copy text

```
if (TextUtils.equals(packageName, "com.whatsapp")){

                                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, helloWorld );

                        }
```

Comment: Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar please read it again. My question is different